# Mixed assembly and C: re-assigning RSP register causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86-64, inline-assembly

I was trying to re-assign stack for a sub-function. I tried to implement that by mix assembly and C on Linux, x86_64 architecture.

Here is how I planed to to:
1. Get a section of memory by `mmap` syscall.
2. pass the mapped memory to asm func, then assign it to RSP register and jump to that function.

C function:

```
typedef struct Context
{
    uint64_t    rbx;    // 0
    uint64_t    rsp;    // 8
    uint64_t    rbp;    // 16
    uint64_t    r12;    // 24
    uint64_t    r13;    // 32
    uint64_t    r14;    // 40
    uint64_t    r15;    // 48
    uint64_t    rip;    // 56
    uint64_t    break_point;    // 64
} Context_st;

main_func()
{
    ...
    Context_st contexts[1];
    Context_st mainContexts;

    // inittialize main stack and the function's stack. This should make the func return to main function, which is this one.
    _init_contexts(contexts);

    // This should backup main function's context and jump to another function with customized stack
    _run_contexts(&mainContexts, contexts);

    printf("Successfully returned\n");       // This could not be executed.

    ...
}

static void _init_contexts(Context_st pContexts[1])
{
    int mmapFlags = MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS;
    const size_t STACK_SIZE = 512;

    asm_init_context(&(pContexts[0]));
    pContexts[0].rip = (uint64_t)_some_func;
    pContexts[0].break_point = (uint64_t)_func_to_go;
    pContexts[0].rsp = (uint64_t)mmap(NULL, STACK_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, mmapFlags, -1, 0);
    pContexts[0].rsp += STACK_SIZE;

    return;
}

static void _run_contexts(Context_st *pMainCtx, Context_st *pSubCtx)
{
    asm_save_main_and_go(pMainCtx, pSubCtx);
    return;
}
```

And assembly functions:

```
#################################################
##
    .text
    .align 4
    .globl asm_init_context
    .type asm_init_context, @function
asm_init_context:
    movq %rbx, (%rdi)
    movq %rsp, 8(%rdi)
    movq %rbp, 16(%rdi)
    movq %r12, 24(%rdi)
    movq %r13, 32(%rdi)
    movq %r14, 40(%rdi)
    movq %r15, 48(%rdi)
    retq

#################################################
##
    .text
    .align 4
    .globl asm_save_main_and_go
    .type asm_save_main_and_go, @function
asm_save_main_and_go:

    movq %rbx, (%rdi)
    movq %rsp, 8(%rdi)
    movq %rbp, 16(%rdi)
    movq %r12, 24(%rdi)
    movq %r13, 32(%rdi)
    movq %r14, 40(%rdi)
    movq %r15, 48(%rdi)

    movl %esi, %eax
    movq (%rsi), %rbx
    movq 8(%rsi), %rsp      # This is the code which causes SIGSEGV
    movq 16(%rsi), %rbp
    movq 24(%rsi), %r12
    movq 32(%rsi), %r13
    movq 40(%rsi), %r14
    movq 48(%rsi), %r15
    movq 56(%rsi), %rdx
    push %rdx
    jmp 64(%rsi)
```

I have marked the asm code which causes SIGSEGV. If I comment it out, the program may correctly run and return to shell. But I do not know why.

Is there anything wrong I did? Or If there is something I need to do additionally to make mmapped memory section capable for RSP register as a customized stack space?

Thank you at advanced !!

---

Updated on Nov 22:

It was very strange: when I switched to another virtual machine, the _func_to_go() was successfully invoked. Although there is another segmentation fault after it returns, it may be known issue because of error stack...

I will keep updated if I replicate the problem. But I hope this remains "WorksForMe".

Special thanks to [@AjayBrahmakshatriya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858773/ajay-brahmakshatriya) and [@Ped7g](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4271923/ped7g). Your discussion pointed out some of my error, and I have corrected or will correct them in my project [here](https://github.com/Andrew-M-C/Linux-Linux_Programming_Template/commit/665f9e6ac4d0cbed21756b5f80a6bc0ec72972bd). :-)

Comment: How to you plan on restoring `%rsp` after returning, since your context `struct` is located on the old stack?

Comment: I am actually learning coroutine with assemblly implementation. The context struct will not be used by `_func_to_go `, therefore it should be OK to re-assign another stack pointer.

Comment: Yes, but do you plan to return back to the original (`main_func`) function? Or just exit from `_func_to_go`?

Comment: I would return to another function which may free allocated memory for this `_func_to_go`. I planned to implement that after I successfully re-assign stack pointer, so the source code listed above may be not complete.

Comment: First thing I will ask you to do is check if `mmap` succeeds. It could have failed and you might be trying to read/write to inaccessible memory.

Comment: Secondly there could be a misalignment (of `%rsp`) when calling into `_func_to_go`. You should read the ABI for the platform you are compiling for.

Comment: Finally you need to attach a debugger and single step from `asm_save_main_and_go` and check where exactly it fails.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya if really the `movq 8(%rsi), %rsp` is SIGSEGV, it can't be alignment issue, it's just simple `mov` into `rsp`. Alignment would cause problems later. So your point about invalid memory is lot more likely. But then I would expect it to crash already at `movq (%rsi), %rbx`.

Comment: Oh, and `pContexts[0].rsp += STACK_SIZE;` does sound fragile, if you `mmap` only `STACK_SIZE`. While it is technically correct, if the stack is completely empty, the `[rsp]` is still considered "top of stack value", and any code reaching for that just for some check purposes will reach outside of `mmap` region, I would rather put some `nullptr` or "canary" value into the new stack, so it will be pointing at `stack_region.end()-8` address, not exactly at `end()`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya mmap() succeeded. And I had try writing the mmaped memory and it worked. I am current working. I will upload my project to GitHub when I return home. Thank you for your following !

Comment: @Ped7g I am current working. I will upload my project to GitHub when I return home. Thank you for your following !

Comment: @Ped7g I don't think that instruction caused the issue. AFAIK there is *no* reason that instruction can fail. Like OP mentioned he has singled that instruction out by observing that the code works fine in its absence. So it must be something that happens because of that instruction. And misalignment here can definitely cause a crash somewhere in like libc.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya indeed, I agree. I have high doubts the code crashes on the `mov rsp,[...]` too. It may be possible, but it's highly unlikely. As I hate AT&T syntax, and I find the topic of context switching mixed with C quite stressful (lot of work, lot of platform specific code, and riding on the edge of UB all the time), I'm reluctant to dig deep into the posted code and seriously imagine what it does. Unless this is educational task, there's little point to implement your own context switching/MT handling code, that's already well implemented and custom solution is very rarely helpful